# Why do QT's iOS components take up so much disk space?

Tags: c++, qt

Completely new to QT and just started installing.

I was pretty surprised to see that QT was going to take up 23GB.

I looked further into this and found out that the majority of the space is taken up by QT's iOS components (15GB).

Why do the iOS components take up so much space while the other components only take up a gig or two?

I'm glad QT's installer gives me full control over what components I install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess really, but I'll go on a limb and assume those are the gigantic debug build static libraries. Because of the (now past but probably still in effect) linking limitations in iOS.

Seeing how Qt5core.dll is 6 mb in release and 112 mb in debug, and that's a dynamic link library, it is not far fetched to have 15 gigs in static debug libs, which take much more space because they include their dependencies rather than linking then dynamically.

I remember accidentally running a debug static build and IIRC it was significant in size.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! It's odd how the Android components don't even compare in file size to the iOS ones. IIRC, they were less than 1GB in total.

Comment: Android uses dynamic linking.